# Moving custom content types and content

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm rebuilding a Drupal 6 site in Drupal 7.  So much needs to change, it doesn't seem worth trying to upgrade, so I'm starting from scratch.

I would love to know if there is an easy way to export all of my content.  I have about 1000 nodes of two different custom content types.  Is there a module to do this?  If not, I guess I just have to sit down and figure out how data is stored in the database in both versions?

Thanks

Comment: Try the [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) modules

Answer (score 1):

Both [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) are modules purpose-built for what you'd like to do. Migrate requires a little more coding at this point, but I like its ease of use a little more than Feeds.

Simply upgrading the site, using CCK for Drupal 7 to migrate your fields and content types, might be a better solution, though. I would create a backup copy of your site and at least give it an hour's worth of trying before resorting to a full-on content migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the site which should give you the nodes and content_types. The content types can then be exported with features while the actual nodes can be moved by moving the nodes table or if you have fields, load all the nodes from the upgrade db and insert them into the new db.